# Почему не воспроизводится видеобекграунд в Chrome?

Tags: html, css, html5

Коллеги, прошу, помогите решить задачу.

САБЖ:
Имеется страница с видеобекграундом.
https://zopflex.com/dr/dr/al/video/
Видео тянется с нашего сервера.
Видео должно быть закольцовано.

ПРОБЛЕМА:
Видео не проигрывается в Chrome!

Прошу, помогите решить этот баг. Или ткните носом в уже существующий пост на портале.

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: 66 версия, все работает

Comment: Возможно adBlock блокирует. Ну или что-то подобное

Comment: У вас нет видео на бэкграунде, а чтобы оно проигрывалось, нужно подключать 3-4 формата под все браузеры, плюс мобильное сафари на айосиках открывает такие видео в своем окне, т.е. побороться тоже придется (я так и не смог(()

Answer (score 0):

Новая политика Гугла и ЮТ по медиа контенту.

https://blog.chromium.org/2017/09/unified-autoplay.html

```
Developer Recommendations: <video> and <audio>

Use autoplay sparingly. Autoplay can be a powerful engagement tool, but it can also annoy users if undesired sound is played or they perceive unnecessary resource usage (e.g. data, battery) as the result of unwanted video playback. 
If you do want to use autoplay, consider starting with muted content and let the user unmute if they are interested in exploring more. This technique is being effectively used by numerous sites and social networks.
Unless there is a specific reason to do so, we recommend using the browser’s native controls for video and audio playback. This will ensure that autoplay policies are properly handled. 
If you are using custom media controls, ensure that your website functions properly when autoplay is not allowed. We recommend that you always look at the promise returned by the play function to see if it was rejected:

var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {

  promise.then(_ => {

    // Autoplay started!

  }).catch(error => {

    // Autoplay was prevented.

    // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.

  });

}
```